# Align Android seekbar with thumb

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I'm trying to align the seekbar to the top of a view, but i can't center it with the thumb.
Is there some kind of "alignCenter" with the RelativeLayout children.

Here's a sample of my xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_fragment_audio_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/black_transparent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_fragment_audio_begin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_fragment_audio_end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_fragment_audio_play"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_play"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sb_fragment_audio"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_above="@id/rl_fragment_audio_player" />
```

For example, Google Play Music does it.

[image: You can see the orange seekbar is well align with the top of the control view]

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: draw a picture maybe?

Comment: I've added an image, you can see it in the right one, the seekbar is well aligned with the view (by the center of the thumb) to the top of the contoller view

Comment: What have you tried so far? Aligning a `SeekBar` that way is no problem at all, but we cannot help you as long as you don't show us your layout.

Comment: The problem is that is not aligning with the bar, but with the thumb, so when i put something like layout_above="@id/...", it's not like the image, there is a space created by the size of the thumb

Comment: @Tsunaze Nice picture.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your xml that has the thumbs and the seekbar?

Comment: I just edited the post so you can see a part of my code

Comment: Are you trying to put the SeekBar above the RelativeLayout below so that the thumb overlaps it(also overlapping the other content that will be above the SeekBar)?

Comment: Yes that's what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the height of your seekbar might vary, unless you specify it different. Here is how you can make sure it fits all, always.

```
android:layout_above="@id/rl_fragment_audio_player"
```

is setting your seekbar bottom above rl_fragment_audio_player top. There is no direct method to specify centerAlignWith but I would remove the space it occupies within it's parent. To know the height of the seekbar you must wait until the global layout has changed. This code should be placed inside your onCreateView

```
sb = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sb_fragment_audio);
    sb.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    sb.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) sb.getLayoutParams();
                    params.setMargins(0, - sb.getHeight() / 2, 0, - sb.getHeight() / 2);
                    sb.setLayoutParams(params);
                    // I suggest you set the seekbar visible after this so that it won't jump
                }

            });
```

The last view in the xml will be in the front. Therefore make sure your seekbar is added after the the other views. Like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_fragment_audio_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    // your bottom panel

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/image_above"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rl_fragment_audio_player" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sb_fragment_audio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/image_above" />
```

Comment: thanks, it work now, quick question, the seekbar never start or end on the sides of the screen, do you know how i can resolve this problem ?

Comment: Yes the SeekBar initiates with a padding if not specified. If you add android:padding="0dp" in the seekbars xml it will be solved. Don't try to do it programmatically, that would result in a misplaced progress.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot, it works exactly like Google Music Now ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a negative margin to the seekbar?

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sb_fragment_audio"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-15dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/rl_fragment_audio_player" />
```

Comment: Yes i did, it kinda work, but is there a good way to do it ? Because i don't want to choose arbitrary a number of dp to marge. Or is it always the same number of dp ? (PS : i choosed -16dp)

Comment: What I would do is to supply my own thumb resources such that I can control the height and I don't need to be worried about different devices. Btw, I agreed this is not a really good way to do it